# Paging results in ndb issue when querying by key

Tags: python, google-app-engine

the scenery is, I need to retrieve some data from the datastore and, the model is:

```
class Player(ndb.Model):
    """Models an individual Player with key."""
    chatId = ndb.StringProperty()
    nickname = ndb.StringProperty()
    firstName = ndb.StringProperty()
    lastName = ndb.StringProperty()
    profilePic = ndb.StringProperty()
    conversationStatus = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=ConversationStatus.IDLE)
    contacts = ndb.KeyProperty(kind="Player", repeated=True)
```

I would like to retrieve players using the keys in the 'contacts' property.

the function 'pageSearchResults' is intended to show a limited set of results according to the page size. The function is defined as follows

```
prevCursorStr = payload['prev_cursor'] if 'prev_cursor' in payload else ""
nextCursorStr = payload['next_cursor'] if 'next_cursor' in payload else ""
players = []
resultsToFetch = 2

if not prevCursorStr and not nextCursorStr:
    players, next_cursor, more = query.order(Player.key).fetch_page(resultsToFetch)
    prevCursorStr = ""
    if next_cursor:
        nextCursorStr = next_cursor.urlsafe() 
    else:
        next_cursor_str = ""
    next_ = True if more else False
    prev = False
elif nextCursorStr:
    cursor = ndb.Cursor(urlsafe=nextCursorStr)
    players, next_cursor, more = query.order(Player.key).fetch_page(resultsToFetch, start_cursor=cursor)
    prevCursorStr = nextCursorStr
    nextCursorStr = next_cursor.urlsafe()
    prev = True
    next_ = True if more else False
elif prevCursorStr:
    cursor = ndb.Cursor(urlsafe=prevCursorStr)
    players, next_cursor, more = query.order(-Player.key).fetch_page(resultsToFetch, start_cursor=cursor)
    players.reverse()
    nextCursorStr = prevCursorStr
    prevCursorStr = next_cursor.urlsafe()
    prev = True if more else False
    next_ = True



result = {
    'players': players,
    'search': payload['search'] if 'search' in payload else "",
    'next_cursor': nextCursorStr if next_ else "",
    'prev_cursor': prevCursorStr if prev else "",
}


return result
```

Let's assume I do the following:

```
keys = player.contacts
query = Player.query(Player.key.IN(keys))
return self.pageSearchResults(query, payload)
```

In this case I have the weird issue that pagination works correctly in straight order, it gives me back the list of results like:
1, 2, -> next page
<- prev page 3

If I click prev page the same function gives me back
3 -> next page 
which is not correct.

Now, the issue disappears if I query a property that is not a KeyProperty.

For debugging purpose I added this code to the previous snippet

```
keys = player.contacts
chatids = []
for key in keys:
    player = key.get()
    chatids.append(player.chatId)

query = Player.query(Player.chatId.IN(chatIds))
return self.pageSearchResults(query, payload)
```

In this case I query the chatId StringProperty, and pagination works like a charm.

I don't really understand what is going on here, can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

The model's key property should be filtered by:

```
keys = player.contacts
query = Player.query(Player._key.IN(keys))
return self.pageSearchResults(query, payload)
```

Note the `_key`. For contacts that matches a key:

`query = Player.query(Player.contacts.IN(keys))`

Comment: thank you, but doing some tests, I got it working by means of `chatdIds = player.contacts
  query = Player.query(Player.chatId.IN(chatdIds))`
here, chatId is not a list either, but it works with IN filter, how is this different from what I was trying to do before? I can't grasp the point here...

Comment: What is the result when querying IN with the StringProperty chatId?

Comment: I get all the players entities having chatId property listed in the given chatIds list

Comment: The ndb IN query performs multiple equality filters inside an OR statement. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries#neq_and_in
So querying by 'property.IN(list)' is just like querying 'property == list[0]' etc. For filtering by entities' key property, try: `query = User.query().filter(User._key > ndb.Key('User', key_id))`. Note the `_key`.

Comment: Modified the answer to match the comments.